# Is it possible to share a file to an Ionic app?

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework

I am trying to share a file to my Ionic app.  In iOS, the sharing looks like this:

[image]

I have implemented sharing a file to an native iOS app in the past using ShareExtension.  Is there a way to share a file to an ionic app (iOS and android) without using native code?

I was hoping there would be a plugin for this, but it doesn't seem like it.

Comment: tried this https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-openwith/blob/master/README.md?

Comment: im getting a weird error when I try to install it:

`Using "requireCordovaModule" to load non-cordova module "child_process" is not supported. Instead, add this module to your dependencies and use regular "require" to load it.`